# What challenge could I issue to a group of computers to prove they are connected via a low-latency connection?

Tags: networking, lan

(Note: Please let me know if this would be a better fit for a more theory-oriented Stack Exchange site)

Let's say I have a group of N computers. I have a direct TCP/IP connection to each from a central server, but I have no idea where the computers are in the world, how they are connected to each other, any middlemen they might be using, etc.

If these computers are spread out geographically, then it is likely that the time it would take to exchange a message with each other is the same as what it would take to exchange a message with me - that is to say, if I were to send a request to one and it was expected to respond within a normal time frame, I know that it could not have colluded with any of its peers to generate a response. However, if that computer has peers close by, then it could exchange information and insights with them in the time frame that they would be expected to respond in.

So, before I start sending actual application requests, I would like to send a challenge to all N of these computers that is solvable in the request time frame if and only if the computers have a much lower-latency connection to each other than with me. What can I ask them to solve?

Some notes:

- My theoretical usage for this would be an online game. Since, for most games, a group of players that's in the same room have a competitive advantage over a group that isn't, I would like to be able to detect this.
- Of course, unless the clients were tamper-proof, they would need an incentive to cooperate with the challenge - otherwise, they could feign latency to appear spread out, then start communicating locally when it actually mattered. I imagine that, in the online game scenario, it would be a requirement for joining a so-called "LAN division", which would feature higher-level competition but would disqualify the team from the "online division" and thus be a trade-off.
- Bonus points if I can detect how many round trips the computers can execute before I notice (e.g. there is a puzzle than can be solved in 3 round trips, but not just 1), and, if not all N computers are connected via low-latency connections, if I can detect which ones do have such connections.
- Note that it is also a possibility for the N computers I am testing to be connected to other computers that are not otherwise part of the test. For instance, there might be a central supercomputer to which all N computers send their requests, for it to coordinate answers. Due to IP spoofing (which is allowed, even under HTTPS, if the computers cooperate), the central supercomputer might also be the one sending the responses.